# Creating a database schema to reflect a JSON object

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

I am in the process of developing my first CRUD app using JavaScript, PHP and MySQL.

I have a large portion of the JS done and have a JSON data structure to hold user created 
parameter changes in my app.

The way the JSON below works is when a user clicks a button called '**save**' a batch of user modifiable data is pushed to the JSON skeleton below. The JSON skeleton values  get replaced outright on each 'save'/push ( In other words the arrays are reset to length = 0 prior to each save and the patch_name is reset as well)

Every time the user clicks 'save' the JSON object will have a single '**patch_name**' , an unlimited number of '**synth**' objects each with any number of stored key/values, and an unlimited number of '**sampler**' objects which are basically identical to the 'synth' objects

The problem is this:

I am having trouble visualizing how to create a MySQL schema to reflect this JSON object.
From what I've read it is bad practice to do the 2 things that my novice intuition leans toward, **1.** Creating a new table for each 'patch' and **2.** Storing entire arrays in tables.
I'm hoping this isn't to 'vague' of a question for SO but I'm basically just looking for someone to give me a small example of how this might look as a MySQL schema.

```
var patch = { 
"patch_name": "oscillating do-dad",
    "sound_type": {
        "synth": [     // each 'synth name' is a draggable div that plays an oscillator
        {synth_name: "synth1",xpos:180,ypos:45},
        {synth_name: "synth2",xpos:200,ypos:45},
        // etc

        ],
        "sampler": [ 
            // same as synth only for divs that trigger audio files instead of oscillators
        ]
    }, 

}
```

Comment: Where both values *and* keys are unknown, you're generally obliged to follow an EAV model - although they're notoriously difficult to work with.

Comment: Well, for the sake of learning lets assume the keys are all known even though I left a portion of the above JSON to the imagination. How would I do it then?

Comment: Did you find out how ?